# How to find skewness of image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

For matrix (say A) using the formula skewness(A(:)) we can easily get the skewness of the whole matrix. But doing same thing for an image (which is also a matrix) its not working.

Say I'm running the following code:

```
>> I=imread('lenna.jpg');
>> s=skewness(I(:))
```

The error coming is

> Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
>   Error in ==> skewness at 39
>   x0 = x - repmat(nanmean(x,dim), tile);

Comment: Use `im2double` after reading the image data and then use `skewness`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I` is of type `uint8` after [`imread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), you can convert it to `double` first by using [`im2double()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2double.html).

Try

```
>> I=imread('lenna.jpg');
>> I2 = im2double(I);
>> s=skewness(I2(:))
```